# Yii2 CSS to asset folder

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have my `site.css` in my `web/css/`

which i declared here

```
namespace frontend\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.min.css'
    ];
}
```

How do i get `AssetBundle` to copy it into the assets folder to make it look like this

`<link href="/frontend/web/assets/2edj2hj2jk/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">`

instead of this?

`<link href="/frontend/web/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">`

or is there another way to achieve this? Basically I want everything in `web/css`, `web/images` and `web/js` to be saved in the assets folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to have those resources copied into `/web/assets` folder than all you need to do is use `$sourcePath` property instead of `$basePath` and `@baseUrl` properties.

You should move your `images`, `css` and `js` folder somewhere else from `web` folder because `AssetManager` will copy the whole content of folder referenced in `$sourcePath`.

Let's say you move it into `frontend/resources`.

```php
namespace frontend\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@frontend/resources';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.min.css'
    ];
}
```

But in fact you **shouldn't do this**. `AssetManager` copies resources into `web/assets` folder to allow direct access to files that wouldn't be normally accessible because they are hidden in `widgets`, `modules` or `vendor` folder. If your resource files are already in `web` folder which is exposed by web server then there is no need to copy them elsewhere.

You will even make it harder to reference images from your view files, because the name of hash subfolder of `web/assets` folder is not fixed and it can change when your resource files changes.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I'm using this plugin to push my assets to aws s3

`https://github.com/white43/yii2-cloud-asset-manager`

Just thought it might be easier to have all static files on S3 and not have to upload it manually.

Comment: If that's the case then you can probably disregard the warning below code. Referencing images might still be an issue.